# Try to import module ActiveDirectory on a linux powershell

Tags: php, powershell

In my webpage I wanted to change the password of some accounts. So I got a script powershell. In this one I need to import the module Active-Directory to change the password of accounts. My server is on CentOS, so I install powershell on it. But when I do : Import-Module ActiveDirectory, the console return 'Import-Module: The specified module 'ActiveDirectory' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.'
Thanks

Comment: The `ActiveDirectory` module comes with RSAT for _Windows_ - it doesn't work on CentOS

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is... you can't. The centos platform version of .net does not support the `[System.DirectoryServices]` types/classes yet, and I doubt they'll be migrated over soon. Powershell's `ActiveDirectory` module requires those to run, so this cannot currently be done in Powershell:

```
[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()
MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "GetCurrentDomain" with "0" argument(s): "System.DirectoryServices is not supported on this platform."
```

An alternative is using ldap commands from centos packages. Here's some examples:

```
# Change a password that you already know - works with almost any configuration
# You can provide the password from a file or as a parameter. By default it will prompt.
# part of package samba-common-tools

smbpasswd -U MyUsername -r ad.domain.tld
  Old SMB password:
  New SMB password:
  Retype new SMB password:
```

Changing a password for an AD user when you don't know the current one is more complicated and requires a much more specific configuration on your machine, but can be done with just `passwd` if:

- your centos machine is joined to the domain correctly
- you are using an admin account with write permission to AD
- You have sssd configured with `chpass_provider=ad` in `\etc\sssd\sssd.conf`

```
passwd DOMAIN\\SomeUsername
```

Otherwise, the best option on linux is through python's ldap module. I'm not as familiar with it, so I'm only linking working example code from a similar question: [Modifying Active Directory Passwords via ldapmodify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316740/modifying-active-directory-passwords-via-ldapmodify)

Answer (score 1):

I know the thread is very old but the alternative is to send invoke requests to your domain controller/other windows server.

Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01 -Credential Domain01\User01 -ScriptBlock { Get-Culture }